# Php - what is this %7Barticle-%3Eid%7D meaning in Codeigniter Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am fetching a id to update a record then in place of id this ->  %7Barticle-%3Eid%7D is showing on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

this is url encode format %7Barticle-%3Eid%7D if you decode it will be {article->id} use 
https://www.urldecoder.org/ this url to decode text

or else use php urldecode()

```
<?php
   $term = urldecode('%7Barticle-%3Eid%7D');
?>
```